# Ошибка Apostrophe not preceded by \

Tags: android

Получаю эту ошибку на следующей строке (на выражение var blocks = [];)

```
<string name="app_name">getbackbreakedblocksmod</string>
<string name="code">
    var blocks = [];
    function destroyBlock(x,y,z,a){
    var id = getTile(x,y,z);
    blocks.push({x:x,y:y,z:z,blockid:id});}
    function procCmd(c){
    if(c=='g'){
    blocks.forEach(function(block){
    setTile(block.x,block.y,block.z,block.blockid);
    });
    }
    }</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке написано, что апострофы должны [экранироваться символом `\`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling).

Очевидно компилятору не нравятся  `'` в строке `if(c=='g')`, должно быть  `if(c==\'g\')`.

Так же проблемы могут быть и с другими символами, вроде `[` , `]` , `{` , `}`  - тогда их тоже нужно экранировать.

Возможно лучше будет заключить всю строку в двойные кавычки (тогда экранировать отдельные символы не нужно):

```
<string name="code">
    "var blocks = [];
    function destroyBlock(x,y,z,a){
    var id = getTile(x,y,z);
    blocks.push({x:x,y:y,z:z,blockid:id});}
    function procCmd(c){
    if(c=='g'){
    blocks.forEach(function(block){
    setTile(block.x,block.y,block.z,block.blockid);
    });
    }
    }"</string>
```